# Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type file

Tags: reactjs, react-component

In an application using react, I have a `form` with `radio` input, which chooses which component will render, but when I change the radio option this warning shows up -

### "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type file to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component"

**Form**

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    export default () => {
        const [link, setLink] = useState("");
        const [arquivo, setArquivo] = useState("");
        const [forma_envio, setFormaEnvio] = useState("");
       
       
        return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="form-check ">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    name="forma"
                    id="forma1"
                    value="File"
                    checked={forma_envio === "File"}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setFormaEnvio(e.target.value);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
             <div className="form-check ">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    name="forma"
                    id="forma2"
                    value="Link"
                    checked={forma_envio === "Link"}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setFormaEnvio(e.target.value);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            {forma_envio === "File" ? (
                <input
                    type="file"
                    className="form-control-file form-control"
                     id="arquivo"`
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        handleUpload(e.target.files[0]);
                    }}
                />
            ) :forma_envio === "Link" (
                <input
                    value={link}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="link"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setLink(e.target.value);
                    }}
                />
            ):
            ("")}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

All states are starting with `""`.

Everything works fine, but I still can't figure how to fix this warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the initial value of `link` is not `null` or `undefined`, but an empty string, like:

```
// const [link, setLink] = React.useState() //  will cause the warning
const [link, setLink] = React.useState('') // correct
```

**EDIT:**
After the question was edited, I noticed the problem:

input tags of type "file" [MUST BE UNCONTROLLED](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag). You should not pass `value` or `onChange` to it. Instead, you should pass a reference and attach it to the input.

```
const arquivo = useRef(null);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        // ...
        <input
            type="file"
            ref={arquivo}
            id="arquivo"
        />
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

This is also a rare situation in which you want to hide a DOM node instead of avoiding the rendering. The File object is stored directly on the DOM, so you must keep this DOM node around, otherwise you will lose the selected files.

```
<input
    type="file"
    ref={arquivo}
    id="arquivo"
    style={{ display: forma_envio !== "File" && "none" }}
/>
```

Complete code at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-fermat-rst1b?file=/src/App.js), without warnings.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the full component code?

Comment: Edited, just didn't put the function that makes the request to the db because it is quite large. but the function just check if the request status is 201 and Redirect to another route

Comment: The problem is the input with type="file" without a value. I'll edit the answer with a working example based on yours.

Comment: This took a while, but I edited. File inputs must be uncontrolled.